# How does one say Pesach in a foreign language?

Tags: passover, language

It is debatable whether Pesach means Passover, as it is called in English, or "hover over" like in Isaiah 31:5.

I am wondering if other languages besides for English use the term Pesach (in their language form) or the term Passover (in their language form) when referring to the Yom Tov/holiday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spanish, non-Jews refer to Pesach as "La Pascua Judia". The term "Pascua" refers to the "Paschal lamb offering" as it's known in English. "Judia" means Jewish, as the Avodah Zarah Festival held on the Sunday after Pesach is also called "Pascua" in Spanish. Please note that Spanish - speaking Jews almost universally refer to the holiday as "Pesach" though they write the final consonant with a "j" as  in Spanish a "j" is used to represent a "ח"

Comment: Same in French, although more often, one may infer from context whether «La Paque» refers to פסח or the similarly-timed Catholic holiday

Comment: Indeed @Noach I once had a conversation with a Masorti French Jew and he was waxing nostalgic about the dishes his grandmother would prepare for "Pâques". When I arched my eyebrows in mock surprise he responded, a little flustered, "La Pâque juive, quoi!"